# PHP- Taking the Largest value from Mysql column of Unique ID

Tags: php, mysql, max, fetch

My current projects consist of Registration of families of different areas in a City. i want to Generate  a Unique ID to each families in which i need this ID for another part of this project.Each area in the city have already a unique number eg: 855, 856, 857,etc

So my plan is to generate unique Family ID by combining unique number already have + text "FM"+ number (1,2,3....) and store this uid to DB along with family details.

For eg (Area-855):  855FM1, 855FM2, 855FM3....

if the last registered family uid is 855FM40 , then next family uid must be 855FM41. so i want to fetch the largest value from uid field. in above eg:, largest is 855FM41. how i do this. ?

i have  simple logic that fetch all uid, then split it after "FM". then find  largest ,etc

How i solve this problem.? is there any simple way other than this.?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Comment: Do you text's other than FM?

Comment: Use a compound primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ORDER command you can sort your data by ordering of one column ascending or descending.

so first we order FamilyID column descending (in sql we use DESC) and then we get the first row which has biggest FamilyID value using  "LIMIT 0,1" command

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM families ORDER BY FamilyID DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Code-only answer is not really recommended as it may confuse OP and future readers. It would be better to add a brief explanation what this code does.

Comment: yeh i get the answer when tried your code... thnx. but can u please explain what this query actually means.? what was its logic.? Selecting Family Id in decreasing order with range from 0 and show 1 row.?

Answer (score 1):

You should use two columns instead of one. For example this:

```
FamilyID
--------
855FM1
855FM2
```

Should be stored as:

```
CityID  FMNumber
------  --------
855     1
855     2
```

This way the data should be easier to manage and less redundant. And yes, it is possible to define primary or unique keys over multiple columns.